# Azure Cosmos DB Stored Procedure With Parameter

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure Cosmos Db and I am working on a simple stored procedure (JavaScript) that needs to return a document if the Id is provided. I don't get "no docs found" when I execute the stored procedure. Bellow is my code:

````
function sample(id) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var query = {
    query: "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id = \'id\'"
};

    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),query,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { id: id, feed: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Queries get automatically scoped to the partition key passed to the stored procedure. So your query is partition key =  and id = . When you skip passing the partition key, it is set to undefined as well.

Can you please try to set it via `FeedOptions.PartitionKey` in .NET or the `x-ms-partition-key` header?

Comment: I don't know how to set that via FeedOptions.PartitionKey. But the query worked after I removed the WHERE clause from the query based on the first part of your answer. There was no need for that part (apparently)